# How to disable implicit type conversion for Constants?

Tags: go, enums, type-conversion, constants, implicit-conversion

I have the following code snippent:

```
type ErrorCode string

const (
    INVALID_REQUEST ErrorCode = "INVALID_REQUEST"
)

type Response struct {
    ErrorCode string `json:"errorCode"`
}

func BuildResponseError(errorCode ErrorCode) string {
    user := &Response{ErrorCode: string(errorCode)}
    response, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return `{"errorCode":"bad_request"}`
    }

    return string(response)
}
```

I can call function **BuildResponseError** like that:

```
BuildResponseError("wrong_request")
```

Is there a way to disable this implicit type conversion? I want to call this function only like this, using a enum value:

```
BuildResponseError(INVALID_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable the possibility to assign a `string` to a variable of your `ErrorCode` type since `ErrorCode`'s underlying type is `string` and according to Go's assignability  rules:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> ...
>
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type

Source: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

So that functionality is built-in into the language.

One way to achieve similar functionality (not exactly the same but the closest you can get) would be to define the type like:

```
type ErrorCode struct {
    Code string
}
```

And then a **variable** (you can't define a constant of that type):

```
var (
    INVALID_REQUEST ErrorCode = ErrorCode{"INVALID_REQUEST"}
)
```

You should then modify your code, of course, to take the `Code` from inside that type to build the response:

```
user := &Response{ErrorCode: errorCode.Code}
```

That way the function can't be called using a `string`, only `ErrorCode` values will be accepted.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qoKrGiJQtxv

Comment: thank you for so good example and explanation.

Comment: Was working on this exact solution, but ended up embedding an anonymous `string` in the struct instead of naming the field, which ends up doing some funky stuff. TIL.